# Android scoped storage, backup huge amount data

Tags: android, backup, android-external-storage, scoped-storage

As we all know starting Android Q (API=29) introduced new [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) concept, which basically prevents access to external files/dirs, except media files. Namely:

1. Programmer can use internal/app specific storage (no limits) - `getFilesDir()`
2. The only external storage can be accessed is via `getExternalFilesDir()`, but during app uninstall data will be deleted
3. There's option to access external storage via `MediaStore`, but it works only for media files
4. App still can read any external file via: `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`

In my case I have app, which stores user data in SQLite database in app specific directory, database size can be up-to several gigs.

In all previous versions of my app users used to backup data to external storage/SD/USB and transfer those data to their new device, so they could continue to use data (it's encrypted database containing any kind of private data, including audio/video/documents and so on).

**Question:** how can I backup this database? I couldn't manage to find appropriate way to save/backup data to any external storage...

P.S. Android autobackup service is unworkable due to the size of database.

Comment: Use SAF to let the user choose a file location with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: Further you can use MediaStore to copy any file.

Comment: `all know starting Android 28 ` You mean 29!?

Comment: @blackapps 1) SAF gives you only `Uri` which can later be used to get `InputStream` - so you will be able only to read
2) `MediaStore` gives access only to media files
3) Sure, it's Android 29 - you're right

Comment: Of course you can write to a saf file too. (There is not much to read from an empty file just created by ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT). No. You can save any file using the MediaStore. I said that before.

Comment: As reads `MediaStore` manual:
*If scoped storage is enabled, the collection shows only the photos, videos, and audio files that your app has created.*

That basically means that `MediaStore` supports only media files in scoped storage

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your reading. But you better believe me and try.